# C array never fills after input from cin

Tags: c++, arrays

The following code never places anything into the two integer arrays, `seqs` and `seq_sizes` but all other variables do contain expected contents when I pause and debug during runtime.

Why would these arrays remain empty despite the calls to place ints into them?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int n,q;
    cout << "n q:" << endl;
    cin>>n>>q;
    int m = 1000000;
    int seqs[m];
    int seq_sizes[n];

    cout << "seqs:" << endl;
    for (auto i=0;i<n;++i){
        cout << i << ":" << endl;
        int take;
        cin>>take;
        seq_sizes[i]=take;
        for (auto j=0;j<seq_sizes[i];++j){
            int take2;
            cin>>take2;
            seqs[i+j]=take2;
        }
    }
    cout << "queries:" << endl;
    for (auto i=0;i<q;++i){
        int seq,index;
        cin>>seq>>index;
        int tally=0;
        for (auto j=0;j<seq;++j){
            tally+=seq_sizes[j];
        }
        cout<<seqs[tally+index]<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Sample input:

2 2
3 1 5 4
5 1 2 8 9 3
0 1
1 3

Comment: What are `n` and `q`?

Comment: they are ints read in, typically < 10. they are correctly read in according to debugger

Comment: FYI: `int seqs[m];` and `int seq_sizes[n];` are not standard C++ when `m` and `n` are not constant expressions (although your compiler may support it as an extension).

Comment: Let me reword that comment.  Please give us the inputs you use to the program.

Comment: @crashmstr that's a good point. I'm solving one of the practice hackerrank questions: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/variable-sized-arrays it requires this, no?

Comment: @NathanOliver updated

Comment: @johnbakers If you need a run-time sized array you want a `std::vector`

Comment: What does "never places anything into the two integer arrays" mean? If you pre-initialise the arrays with a bogus value, and then print them out at each step, what is their contents?

Comment: @NathanOliver yes, but cannot use vector on this hackerrand practice question

Comment: @johnbakers `std::vector` would be a C++ way of doing it, another (less overhead but less preferred) option would be using `new` to allocate the array dynamically. VLAs are a C feature that has not found its way into the C++ standard.

Comment: @crashmstr And is finding its way *out* of the C one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (auto i=0;i<n;++i){
    cout << i << ":" << endl;
    int take;
    cin>>take;
    seq_sizes[i]=take;
    for (auto j=0;j<seq_sizes[i];++j){
        int take2;
        cin>>take2;
        seqs[i+j]=take2;
    }
}
```

check the functioning of this loop(considering your input)
it sets seq_sizes[0] = 3 once and then it is reinitialized to 1.
Same happens again and again which is causing the error.
Consider changing i+j in line seqs[i+j]=take2;

Comment: @johnbakers check this implementation ideone.com/o8lXNi it works fine